# Is it always a good idea to run a tasks on other threads than EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Title question may sound like a weird one, but today I came across one problem. There is a button in `JDialog` which starts a long running task. If I start this long running task via `SwingWorker`, the user is able to close this `JDialog` with X button in the to right corner and I have to deal with that somehow. Actually, user can click anythere in the App and it means that it requires some more code to deal with many other situations. However, I have another choice. When user clicks this button which starts a long running task, I can show a hourglass mouse pointer and run this task on EDT. In this way I do not have to deal with situations when user can click anythere and start other actions or change program state.

So my question is: should I always blindly follow the best practise and execute long running tasks on other threads than EDT?

Comment: Launching long running tasks in separate threads gives you more control over these tasks execution and failing rather than launching such tasks in EDT.  Moreover, launching long running task in EDT may and most probably result in user interface freezing issues, that is not a good idea.

Comment: But in this scenario it is acceptable, because i do not want that user do any actions. My point is that sonetimes it is more convenient to run a task on EDT.

Comment: from user's point of view, freezing the entire user interface will look bad and will look like a problem rather than normal working condition for an application. Support team will get a high pressure upon such events.

Comment: I’m not sure if I agree with you. As I said, I’m showing an hourglass mouse pointer to indicate that system is busy and other user interaction is not allowed. If program should work like that it is easier to achieve that running task on EDT.

Comment: what if your hourglass is stopped rotating and moving and the whole interface gets frozen upon a complex process running in EDT? From my point of view it is a disturbing thing and your support team would not thank you for such events.

Comment: Why is it supposed to stop? In what circumstances it may stop? It may stop in both cases equaly.

Comment: For example when the garbage collector starts, or the operating system decides to do something with the resources acquired by your application, etc etc.

Comment: As I said, it may stop in both cases equaly. If I run long task on other thread, I also indicate user about long task in progres with an hourglass. If it would disappear the user will not know that a task is running.